# Reducing occupied memory by multidimensional variant array in vba

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory, variant

I have a rather large array:

```
Global add_vit(0 To 6, 0 To 6, 2 To 18, 0 To 1300, 0 To 8) As Variant
```

Which I fill partially fill up in module a, sub one, (which takes a long time). I wish to execute Module a sub one only once.

Once the execution has finished, I want to acces the above variant array in module b, sub two, and run module b sub two multiple times independently, in order to verify the code I am working on in module b, sub two.

I learnt that the "Global" part means that the the array will be filled/preserved even after module a, sub one is completely finished. That is what I need, but at the same time, I run on the border of getting out of memory errors.

I have several of such arrays in run module a, sub two which are all interlinked, and in certain conditions I need specific entries to be copied to other specific entries of arrays. This also prevents me from separating the computation of this last global array into another module.

I am also confused by the perceived randomness of when a "out of memory" error occurs, when I run the same script with the same initial conditions at different times, thoug I assume it is because the amount of memory available for excel is not static, but dependent on other processes I use on my laptop simultaneously.

**Does anyone have a suggestion on how to maintain the same amount of entries (for doubles and longs), (or doubles and booleans) in storage accesible, (approx. 8.000.000) whilst still being able to access them from different modules when the initial computation is finished without occupying so much memory?***

*Without manually storing them into an excel sheet for it is tedious and slows down computation drastically.

I also try to reset the entire array manually before computations with the following script:

```
For A = 0 To 6
    For B = 0 To 5
        For C = 2 To 18
            For d = 0 To 1300
                For e = 0 To 4
                    add_vit(A, B, C, d, e) = ""
                Next e

                For f = 6 To 7
                    add_vit(A, B, C, d, e) = False
                Next f
            Next d
        Next C
    Next B
Next A
```

Comment: What is the issue resetting the array or memory management?

Comment: You're really not going to beat an array for memory consumption.  The only overhead is 20 bytes for the [SAFEARRAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482(v=vs.85).aspx) header (or 24 on a 64bit  machine), plus 8 bytes per dimension.  The rest of the memory use is just for the items you store in it. You either need to use persistent storage (either a worksheet or something else) or try to reduce your memory requirement.

Comment: Why is it a `Variant` array? Is the data inside it really heterogeneous? I say this because you might be able to reduce the required memory size if you use a basic data type, i.e. `Integer`.

Comment: `Global` is deprecated syntax. If your variable needs to be global to the project, use `Public`. If your variable can be private to the module, use `Private`

Comment: @cyboashu Thank you, I started out with that problem, manually solved it and then realized it was a memory issue and forgot I started out different, I altered it.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you, I am going to convert the booleans into 1 and 0's so that I can reduce the storage use from 16 bytes minimum to 8 bytes where possible.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I believe when I set it to Public, the values of the array will be lost after module a sub one has been executed. If I store them as Global, they will be stored even after the module a sub one is done.

Comment: @MaximilianbrutusIII That's not true, to make it global you just declare it `Public` and place its declaration outside any sub, in a normal code module i.e. `Module1`

Comment: A few suggestions: does it really need to be global, can't you jut pass it around (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx)? Also, look at your variable scope (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html) - at what point are all your other variables being garbage collected, could you refactor your code to run more efficiently?

Comment: just to throw in that to _reset_ an array you can use [`Erase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264507(v=office.15).aspx) statement (i.e.: `Erase add_vit`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your tips!

@A.S.H Thank you I have tested and validated that indeed a public also retains it's value after the the sub/module has been completed. 
So I appologize @ThunderFrame , you were right, I could use a public instead of a sub, thank you.

@user3598756 thank you, that was the statement I initially was looking for, the `erase` statement.

@Absinthe I forgot to mention that module 2 is actually a sub in a form that is generally called with userfomX.show, I still have to look up how the variables are passed through to that. But mainly the separation of the two modules was what I was looking for, which meant that I wanted to run module 2 without needing to run module1 everytime whilst still using the stored output of a single run of module one.

Thank you so much everyone, you are awesome!